# Golang quick initialize sql.Null*

Tags: go

Here is small code snippet that workds well:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "database/sql"


type Something struct {
    Int64 int64
    Valid bool
}

func main() {
    var s = sql.NullInt64{1, true}  // <- unkeyed fields warning
    var s1 = Something{1, true}
    fmt.Printf("Hello, %#v %#v\n", s, s1)
}
```

But `go vet` complains:

`test.go:12: database/sql.NullInt64 composite literal uses unkeyed fields`

Question is: why it does complain on line 12 and does not complain on line 13 here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand this behavior, we can simply look at the source for `go vet` in the `go.tools` repository.

In [`composite.go:46`](https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/5ebbcd132f1e9c320204496eeeaac47007339543/cmd/vet/composite.go#L46), it checks the type of the composite literal. If the literal is part of the current package, `go vet` does not warn you about unkeyed values.

```
// A simple type name like t or T does not need keys either,
// since it is almost certainly declared in the current package
```

This check likely exists because an external package could change the struct fields and break your code. Keyed fields make this less of a problem.

Answer (score 3):

It's asking you to add the keys, e.g.

```
var s = sql.NullInt64{Int64: 1, Valid: true}
```

Comment: Yes, but other structs with 1-2 elements i used to initialize without keys and just wondering what is different about this type, why it suddenly needs explicit keys

Comment: @Dfr: It doesn't *need* keys. `go vet` is suggesting that you use them to prevent possible errors (like renaming or reordering of the struct fields).